# TicTacToe click() scope error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a TicTacToe game on JavaScript with a bot. The main thing right now is that when a div with a class ".freeSpot" is clicked, this.class must be changed to a different class => the click function works only on ".freeSpot" classes. In this function I also added a function for the bot's turn. Analogically, the bot changes the middle square's class to ".botMarked" and player should not be able to change that middle square, but it does.

```
$('.freeSpot').click(function () {
        console.log(this); 
        $(this).attr('class', "marked");
        $(this).html("X");
        winBool = checkWin();
        if (winBool == true) {
            alert("Player wins");
        }
        botTurn();
    });

    //TODO- finish for every turn
    function botTurn() {
        var Q = $('#Q').text();
        var W = $('#W').text();
        var E = $('#E').text();
        var A = $('#A').text();
        var S = $('#S').text();
        var D = $('#D').text();
        var Z = $('#Z').text();
        var X = $('#X').text();
        var C = $('#C').text();
        if (S != "X") {
            $("#S").attr("class", 'botMarked');
            $("#S").html("O"); 
        }
```

I also noticed that if I call the botTurn() function outside the .click function, the program is working properly, what do I do ?

full project: https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/TicTacToe/tree/master/TicTacToe%20jQuery/ticTacTIe/TicTacToe/TicTacToe

Answer (score 0):

The function is bound to the object with the .freeSpot class. So when later the class is removed the binding remains.

You can try several options,

1. Check if the object still has .freeSpot before you execute your code.
2. Bind to the parent of the element. Such that only childs with .freeSpot class will trigger the event. [JQuery Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)